# Overwriting Changing font-family react native android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts, font-family

In the android OS you can change font-family in the settings. I am making a react-native app and I don't want to the device to load a different font than I am setting for my app.

I am having trouble finding answers on how to disable this function in the android OS. I see lots of stuff for font scaling but nothing to disable changing font from within the android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin, look in to setting the  prop called allowFontScaling to false, this is keep your Font the same to what your app intentionally needs.

Link:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#allowfontscaling

Comment: We already have fontScaling set to false, it does disable the textSize accessibility feature but does not disable Android users from using Gothic Sans in the app.

Comment: @JustinLinn any luck finding the solution for this?

Comment: No luck have not written RN is a while at this point :(

Answer (score 0):

I needed my font family to stay the same only for my apps header so I just took a screen shot of the font I wanted and added the screen shot for my header instead of a Text component.